# Azure Shared Access Signature At a Folder Level

Tags: azure

Azure [SAS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee395415.aspx)

From what I have read you can put a SAS URI in the browser and bring up the file

You can also create a SAS with list and read permission to the container.  In .NET I follow how to use that.

Can you map that SAS list and read as a network drive in Windows Explorer and see the file?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, for now, there is no existing tool able to map the azure storage as a network drive by SAS. (There are tools which can achieve it by account and primary key.)

The most similar tool which can allow user access the azure storage with GUI through SAS is Azure storage explorer. It's free and released by Microsoft.

**Besides, the SAS can only be deployed on container level or blob level. We can not apply SAS on folders. Because there is no concept of folder in Azure storage. The folder is actually the part of the blob name.**

Here is the screenshot of my lab:

[image: storage explorer]